# Get Itinery detals from Sabre API

Tags: sabre

We are developing a .Net MVC application which display travel itenary information of our employees and it is read only  . We are making use of Sabre to Book the tickets .

The ticket booking is a manual process and because of that no information regarding the booking is saved in our database.

Question 1 .

The new .Net app is developed to give each employees a read only view of there Itinary . How this could be achieved ?

Question 2 .

The Service endpoint [TravelItineraryReadRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Get_Itinerary) is expecting a "UniqueID" which we are not having . Is it same as the PNR number or how can we obtain the "UniqueId" ?

Question 3.

The Service endpoint [DailySalesReportLLSRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/fulfill/Get_Sales_Reports) is returning a list of IssuanceData which contains "ItineraryRef" .Can I use this id as "UniqueId" for TravelItineraryReadRQ  ?

Question 4 .

In the TravelItineraryReadRQ response is there Hotel information available or do we need additional API call for that ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you already have a webservices contract, if not, you'll have to contact their sales department (or account executive).

Question 1 .
I will not go into the programming details, this is for you to handle. As you put bellow the service would be [TravelItineraryRead](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Get_Itinerary)

Question 2 .
It is the 6 characters of the reservation id, a.k.a. PNR (Passenger Name Record) or Record Locator.

Question 3.
Yes

Question 4 .
If the reservation contains a hotel segment, then yes:
TravelItineraryReadRS\TravelItineraryItineraryInfo\ReservationItems\Item\Hotel

Answer (score 0):

Question 2.
The Service endpoint TravelItineraryReadRQ is expecting a "UniqueID" which we are not having. Is it same as the PNR number or how can we obtain the "UniqueId"?

Ans: TravelItineraryReadRQ  "UniqueId" means PNR.